# Public Labels(Pointers)

Tags: vb.net

I am working with VB 2010 for an application which requires me to go back to a sub. After some digging, I found out GoSub is no longer supported. I tried using Goto but apparently you can't use it outside the sub the label is in. I tried calling the sub put the parameters were not known to me.

`Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork`

I do not want to use the RunWorkerAsync because the worker will already be working. Please advise me on this matter.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Could you rephrase it or tell us where you are trying to call this Sub from?

Comment: Don't use unecessary tags in your title.

Comment: You need to look into VB.NET language and the OOP approach before going further.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem using procedural logic with an object-oriented tool.

If I understand you correctly, the sub is calling another section of code, and needs to return to the sub after it's finished. Make the called code itself a function or sub, and call it from the primary sub routine.

Comment: I am actually trying to make an alarm application. I was trying to use FileIO to achieve this. It should read the time from a file and check the times.But you would need to change the time sometime.So I made another form to write to the file. The problem is after the gile is written to it is not being read.I need to go back to the sub to restart the checking process.